# How to connect Advantage Data Architect using various sources(PowerShell, CMD, Python etc.)?

Tags: adt, windows-scripting

Can anyone let me know how to connect Advantage Data Architect using various sources(PowerShell, CMD, Python etc.)

Comment: We’d love to help you, but your question lacks information and clarity. You should also include any research you have already done.  To improve your chances of getting an answer, here are some tips: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: No we cannot! On this site, you should ask a single question, based upon a [mcve] of your code, and supporting information. You cannot ask for solutions using multiple languages, and with no code, debugging information, or problem details. Please [edit] your question, to ask about only one scripting language and with the code that you're having a specific issue with that we can replicate.. Please also take time to read through all of the pages of [ask], to assist you in making those changes.